# Configuring ipython notebook for iOS use?

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, safari

tl;dr: I'm trying to set up an iPython notebook server on a digitalocean droplet, and it works from OSX but not from mobile safari on my iPad.  But it's just a http interface to execute code on the server, so there's no reason it shouldn't work the same on both devices.  I suspect there's some kind of dependency that it needs to work on iOS, which comes baked into OSX.

To clarify, by request: iPython notebook is a web-based way to run python code in a reproducible way (all the cool data science kids are doing it this way), and it's available in server form.  So what I'm trying to do is run the code on the network through a browser on my server.

-I know that iPython notebooks CAN be configured to run on iPad (128gb air2 with latest ios8 updates), and that none of my local settings (JavaScript, etc.) are prohibiting it, because I can get the demo notebook (available at https://try.jupyter.org) to run and to execute code from mobile safari on my iPad.

- I also know that the notebook server I have running on my digitalocean droplet (running Ubuntu 12.04, set up with pretty much everything on defaults, and installed via anaconda package) is properly configured at least to work on full-size computers.  It runs fine on my macbook (2013-edition 13in RMBP, specced out, running 10.9.5).

Yet when I tried and access the notebook server from ipad, it will start up the server, and it will create a new notebook, however, the notebook hangs in "connecting to kernel" status and will not execute code in cells (trying to execute code just gives no response).

I'm pretty bad at networking, so all I can do is take some guesses right now as to why this might be.  To wit, my totally uninformed guesses are:

1. There's some kind of authentication issue?  I've SSH'ed into the digitalocean server from my Mac, maybe it's using the ssh keys for that somehow to authenticate for the ipython notebook, and since they're missing on my iPad, it's just silently failing there?
2. There's some kind of dependency for ipython notebooks that exists locally on the Mac but not on iPad, and which the jupyter demo provides server-side?

But I have no clue how to figure out if the issue is 1, 2, or something else, or how to fix.  Does anyone have any insight?  Thanks so much!

Comment: If a notepad does run and another does not you have to start by copying bits from the bad one to the good one until the good one breaks - then you have a better idea of what the issue is

Comment: Ah as the demo notebook is on one server and the fail is on another serve er then the issue is on the server - start here with running the same notebook to both servers. Also python is not normally run on an iPad so when you say "execute code on the iPad" of course it won't so you need to make it clearer what you are doing

Comment: Thanks Mark.  The code is supposed to be executed on the server.  And there's no specific code, I'm trying to get it running, so I've just been starting blank notebooks and executing print statements---which run on the demo server from iPad but not on my server from iPad.  Even though my server runs fine from Mac.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes please edit to show - and I think that means the question can be made much shorter. My next question would be does a web page on the server be loved on the iPad

Comment: I've edited to clarify some.  And yes, ordinary web pages on the server load fine on the ipad.

Comment: Do you use a self-signed certificate in the server?

Comment: @PaulGowder Did you ever manage to solve this? I have the exact same issue with several servers that we are running.